# Celsius to Fahrenheit program wont compile double to float error

Tags: java, temperature

```
    /* 
    This program will convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and display a table 
    of their Fahrenheit equivalents.
    */
    // ---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5--------6---------7
    // 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890

    public class CelsiusToFarhenheit
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          //Variables
          float fhdeg;
          float celdeg = 0;

      while (celdeg <= 20)
          {
             fhdeg = 1.8 * celdeg + 32;

          }
      if (celdeg <= 20)
          {
             System.out.printf( "    %3d C = %5.1f F\n", celdeg, fhdeg );
             celdeg++;
          }
      }
    }
```

I keep getting this error...

> CelsiusToFarhenheit.java:22: error: incompatible types: possible lossy
>   conversion from double to float
>            fhdeg = 1.8 * celdeg + 32;
>                                 ^ 1 error

what I don't get is if i'm initializing them as floats...what's going on?
and since I can't get it to initialize, i'm unaware of whether I have any other errors or if it will even print out the table the way I would like.

Comment: `1.8` change to `1.8f`

Comment: btw, if you run your code, as it is, it will run forever!! Your while loop will never end!

Comment: lol @abhishek  I noticed that...when i ran it. what's causing that? and I just got a clearer view on what im supposed to be doing but, I cant get the how of it...so, the table is supposed to print all the numbers from 0-20 if u just give a gist of what im missing, I can attempt to figure it out.

Comment: just move the two lines in `if` clause to `while` loop after `fhdeg = 1.8 * celdeg + 32;` line or close the `while` loop after `if`block :)

Comment: I get this now... 
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Float
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
 at CelsiusToFarhenheit.main(CelsiusToFarhenheit.java:25)

Comment: you have to change `%3d` in the format string to `%3f` because `d` is for integers and `celdeg` is a `float`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fhdeg = 1.8 * celdeg + 32;`

`1.8` is a literal of type `double`. When you multiply a `double` and a `float`, the result is going to be a `double`, which doesn't fit in a `float`. Use the `f` suffix to make it a `float` literal:

```
fhdeg = 1.8f * celdeg + 32.0f;
```

Comment: just note - 32 in original code is integer and promoted to float, so you could omit `.0f` here, but `32.0f` makes intent more clear and thus preferable

Comment: well now. that makes a bit of sense.  thank you.

Comment: unfortunately, my code doesn't do anything now when it compiles. the instructions honestly weren't too clear on whether a user was supposed to enter a specific value or if the program was supposed to automatically print the conversions...I know it's supposed to go from 0-20 but all i'm getting is...absolutely nothing.

Comment: That's because you have a loop `while (celdeg <= 20)` which just keeps going around forever when `celdeg` is `<= 20`.

Comment: @jesper  so, do I need another if or while loop? and why wont it print. i'm sorry I missed a few sections of the last chapter due to a death in the family last week, and my teacher has yet to respond to the msg I sent him when it happened :/ it's probably something simple that im missing

Comment: First get rid of the `while` loop and the `if` statement and run your program. It should print one line. Then learn [how to use `while`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and use it correctly in your program

Comment: getting rid of both of those made the program do nothing. Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Float
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
 at CelsiusToFarhenheit3.main(CelsiusToFarhenheit3.java:23)

Answer (score 0):

`1.8` is a `double`, and makes the entire expression `1.8 * celdeg + 32` a `double`. Java refuses the implicit conversion of this `double` to `float` upon assignment to `fhdeg`.

Instead, you can write `fhdeg = (float)(1.8 * celdeg + 32);`

This leaves the computation as `double` and only converts to `float` at the time of assigning the value to `fhdeg`.

Comment: thank you. unfortunately...now my code doesn't work at all. lol!

Comment: @L-G Of course not. The condition of the `while` loop is `celdeg <= 20` and you do not change `celdeg` inside the body of the `while`.  But your question is about the compiler warning, so I answered about that.

Comment: so, in the while statement if I use   while (celdeg <= 20)
          {
             fhdeg = 1.8 * celdeg + 32;
             celdeg++;
          }
would that make a difference? I also changed float fhdeg; to float fhdeg = 0; since it wasn't initalizing

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, float (32 bit) can't accommodate double (64 bit). Check [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), but you can accommodate float in double.

For your program to work, you need to convert 1.8 to float by suffixing f, that is 1.8f or make your variables as double.